# How to use iTextSharp to save certain pages to a MemoryStream and return selected page as base64 string

Tags: c#, itext, memorystream

Using iTextSharp, I was able to read a base64 string and convert certain pages into local files using a `FileStream`. I want to do the same without saving to the local filesystem, using `MemoryStream` and only returning the selected pages to the calling function as a base64 string.

```
// function takes reader and start and end page and destination file path as parameter. 
public static void ExtractPages(PdfReader pdfReader, string sourcePdfPath,
                                string outputPdfPath, int startPage, int endPage)
{
    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document sourceDocument = null;
    PdfCopy pdfCopyProvider = null;
    PdfImportedPage importedPage = null;

    try
    {
        reader = pdfReader;
        sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

        // old code to save selected pdf into local file system.
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outputPdfPath, FileMode.Create);

        // memory stream created but not been used yet!
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, fileStream);

        sourceDocument.Open();

        // save selected page into local file system
        for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
        {
            importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
        }

        #region TestMemoryStream

        // TODO: New code to be added and return selected page data as bas64 string

        #endregion

        sourceDocument.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use memory stream exactly like FileStream.  After writing you must set the position property to zero before reading otherwise you do not get any results.

Comment: @jdweng - I tried that as well, but the byte[] of the memory stream is incorrect, I cannot convert the pdf back using online tools. any hints?

Comment: Memory stream works exactly like filestream.  So you must be having a encoding issue.  Stream classes often default to ASCII (even through msdn says otherwise) so first thing I normally do is to add to all my stream classes Encolding.UTF8.  Ascii encoding remove non-printable characters.

Comment: What tools are you using?  The tools may be bad.  Really sound like an encoding issue.  Make sure you use UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out the issue, my modified code is below.

```
reader = pdfReader;
sourceDocument = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(startPage));

//FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(outputPdfPath, FileMode.Create);
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

pdfCopyProvider = new PdfCopy(sourceDocument, memoryStream);
sourceDocument.Open();

for (int i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++)
{
    importedPage = pdfCopyProvider.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    pdfCopyProvider.AddPage(importedPage);
}

sourceDocument.Close();
reader.Close();

byte[] content1 = memoryStream.ToArray();

// var bas64 = Convert.ToBase64String(content1);
string bas64New = Convert.ToBase64String(content1);
```